# F# interactive script load management

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

Suppose I have the following scripts:

`C.fsx`

```ml
namespace FruitSalad

type Cherry =
  {
    Cherry : int
  }
```

`B.fsx`

```ml
#load "./C.fsx"

namespace FruitSalad

type Banana =
  {
    Banana : int
    Cherry : Cherry
  }
```

`A.fsx`

```ml
#load "B.fsx"
#load "C.fsx"

open FruitSalad

type Apple =
  {
    Apple : int
    Banana : Banana
    Cherry : Cherry
  }

let c =
  {
    Cherry = 3
  }

let a =
  {
    Apple = 1
    Banana =
      {
        Banana = 2
        Cherry = c
      }
    Cherry = c
  }

printfn "%A" a
```

Running `A.fsx` gives this error:

> error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
> 'FSI_0001.FruitSalad.Cherry'
> but here has type
> 'FSI_0002.FruitSalad.Cherry'

I can fix this by removing `#load "C.fsx"` from `A.fsx`.

However, maintaining this is awkward for much larger script projects.

Does F# support something like "include once" so that this is not necessary?

Comment: There is no support for "include once". If you have to have the code in multiple files, it's usually a good idea to organize them in a project. It's cleaner and more reliable that way anyway. If you're using this kind of setup for debugging and experimentation, a common practice is to have a "header" file that includes all the scripts in the right order.

Comment: Yes I have "header" files, but with a tree of projects with dependencies it's quite a lot of effort to maintain! Contrast this to Node where you can `require` the same file more than once and it won't complain.

Comment: In Node, `require` is the normal (and the only) way of connecting modules, but in F# it is not. The normal way is the project file. Scripts are not intended for complex systems, they're mostly for debugging and one-off stuff. You're trying to use the thing for the purpose for which it was never intended.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the comment by Fyodor that having a project might be easier. Note that you can create a project with a number of `*.fs` files in it, but still also have a `*.fsx` file that loads all the files from the project. This way, the IDE will read information from the project (and all your autocomplete will work), but you will also be able to run everything from a script file, which just needs to `#load` all the `*.fs` files in the correct order.

Another option that might help you if you prefer to stick to scripts is to use `#load` with multiple files at the same time. In the case above, you should be able to do:

```
#load "./B.fsx" "./C.fsx"
```

This way, F# interactive will know that you are loading these two files at the same time and will not create a separate version of `C.fsx` while loading `B.fsx`.

Comment: I didn't realize `#load` coudl take multple files, that's useful!

Comment: I have given a simplified example for the question, but in the case where you want to run a test script that depends on multiple projects, a `*.fsx` file will not work if there is a shared dependency in the tree.